# Need help understanding how to apply Bayes and an estimator together to solve problem

Tags: probability, statistics, bayes-theorem

I'm getting stuck on this problem that I'm looking at and I am unable to figure out how to start solving this:

"A manufacturing process produces a large number of components each day, and most of these components will meet all specifications listed for the components. Let $p$ be the probability that a component will meet all specifications, and assume that one component meeting specifications is independent of other components meeting specifications. The value of $p$ varies from day to day according to the prior distribution:

$$
\pi(p) = 9p^8\quad 0\le p\le 1
$$

A sample of $n = 5$ components from the production of one day was inspected, and it was found that 4 of the 5 components met all specifications. Find the Bayes estimator of $p$ for this day."

I'm assuming I may to use Baye's Theorem in conjunction with a point estimator, but I'm not entirely sure how to set it up...

Thanks in advance for any input!

Comment: Hints: conditioned on the value of $p$, the number of components that meet specifications is a _binomial_ random variable with parameters $(5,p)$ and thus you can figure out $P\{X = 4\mid p\}$. Then, find $P\{X = 4\}$ using the law of total probability and then the _conditional density_ of $p$ given that $X = 4$.

Answer (score 1):

I will construe your statement about the prior distribution to mean the prior *density*.

The likelihood is
$$
L(p) = \Pr(\text{4 successes in 5 trials} \mid p) = \binom 5 4 p^4(1-p)^1. 
$$
We don't care about the constant $\dbinom 5 4$ because we will normalize at the end.  So $L(p)\propto p^4 (1-p)$ and the prior density is proportional to $p^8$.  Multiply these, getting $p^{12}(1-p)$.  If you want the posterior density, you need a constant $c$ such that
$$
\int_0^1 p^{12}(1-p)\,dp = 1.
$$
But you should also recognize this as the Beta density with parameters $13$ and $2$.